# Linux C socket how to prevent 2 forked process from accepting the same connection when using epoll?

Tags: c, sockets, fork, epoll, persistent-connection

```
for (int t = 0; t < physicalCoreCount; t++) {
        int pid = fork();
        if (pid==0) {
            // setting up epoll    
            epoll_fd = epoll_create1(0);                
            event.data.fd = listenSocketfd;
            event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
            ret = epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, listenSocketfd, &event);                
            events = (epoll_event*)calloc(LISTENQ, sizeof(event));
           
            //*****/
            while (1) {
                int ndfs = epoll_wait(epoll_fd, events, curfdCount, -1);
                if (ndfs==-1) {                        
                    continue;
                }
                for (int i=0; i < ndfs; i++) {
                    if (events[i].data.fd == listenSocketfd) { // original listener
                        int new_connfd = accept(events[i].data.fd, (sockaddr*)&clientaddr, &clientlen);
                        if (new_connfd==-1) {
                            if (errno==EAGAIN || errno==EWOULDBLOCK) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            else exitPerrorLog("accept()");
                        }

                        set_non_block(new_connfd);
                        event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
                        event.data.fd = new_connfd;
                        if (epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, new_connfd, &event) < 0)
                            exitPerrorLog("epoll_ctl");

                        clientaddrOfFd[new_connfd] = new sockaddr_in();
                        memcpy(clientaddrOfFd[new_connfd], &clientaddr, sizeof(clientaddr));
                        curfdCount++;
                    }   
                    else {
                        process(events[i].data.fd, clientaddrOfFd[events[i].data.fd]);
                        //epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, events[i].data.fd, &event);                           
                        if (curfdCount > 10000) curfdCount = 10000; //curfdCount--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem appears because I'm trying to implement persistent connection (not closing after response). However, child 0 can accept() a socket file descriptor X, process it, but later child 1 can accept() the same file descriptor. Since I didn't close the connection on child 0 (to implement HTTP1.1 keep-alive), now 2 children are reading/writing to the same file descriptor.

What's a way to prevent this problem? Thank you.

**Edit:** Important update: so the main problem is that I thought 2 same FD means it's the same connection, I want to avoid that since it would lead to 2 children reading/writing the same thing. If that situation doesn't happen (read/write overlap) then I think the question is solved. Can someone confirm?

Comment: Only one process can accept a particular connection.

Comment: The two child process may get the same fd return value from `accept` but they should be different connections. Use `getsockname` to check the client address and port number that each child is connected to.

Comment: @IanAbbott ohhh, I thought same FD means it's the same client

Comment: @IanAbbott But in the case it's indeed from the same client, then does letting 2 child processes accepting 2 connections have lower performance than just accepting once? I wish to reuse (established) connection

Comment: "I thought same FD means it's the same client" - each child has the same set of in-use file descriptors after the fork (because the parent does not close or open any more file descriptors between the forks), so the lowest unused file descriptor will be the same for each child. The `accept()` call will return the lowest unused file descriptor, which will be the same for each child.

Comment: @IanAbbott I didn't know that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating multiple epoll instances and registering for edge-triggered events on the listening socket in each one.  Naturally, you will get an event from each one when a new connection becomes available to accept.  However, only one process can successfully accept each connection.  As observed in comments, two different children might accept connections that are assigned the same file descriptor number in the respective processes, but that doesn't mean they refer to the same socket.

You have several options, but prominent among them are:

- use a single epoll instance, shared by all the processes.  You can get this automatically by having the parent create it before forking off any of the children.  In this case, only one child will receive each edge-triggered event.  Of course, if the children intend to register for events that should be received only by them, then this isn't going to work very well.
- just accept (no pun intended) that multiple processes will receive events when a connection becomes available, and deal with it.  That appears to be what you're doing now (by ignoring `EAGAIN` and `EWOULDBLOCK` errors from `accept()`), and I see no particular reason why you shouldn't keep doing it.

Comment: Is letting 2 child accept 2 connections from the same client slower than reusing an already established connection? Basically this problem only arises because I want to detect if a connection already exist, and if yes then use it. But it isn't working with this model. I've tried the option you listed, but it will won't solve this specific issue (i.e reusing instead of creating new connection).

Comment: Or should I just let 2 children serve 2 different connections to the same client?

Comment: @HuyLe, in principle, reusing existing connections has the potential to be faster than requiring new ones to be established.  But the additional complication is probably not worth it if establishing a new connection for each request is still fast enough.  Moreover, although I accept that your application is not working as you want, the question's claim that multiple processes accept the same connection is not plausible.  The true nature of the issue being unclear, it's hard to judge whether it is even associated with the code presented in the question at all.

Comment: I clarified the problem in my Edit. So the "accepted connections" aren't the same, they just have the same file descriptor number. For example child 1 and 2 both get (new_connfd = accept()) == 5. In that case, do I get any read/write overlap problem (since 2 processes are writing to the same FD number) ?

Comment: @HuyLe, the sockets provided by different calls to `accept()` are different and independent, no matter what the process, the file descriptor number, or the remote peer.  In your example scenario, no, there is no cross talk between the two separate processes communicating over sockets with the same file descriptor number.

Comment: Thanks! I guess that can be the accepted answer